# Is there a way to get the text message input field from an iMessage extension?

Tags: ios, imessage-extension

I would like to get the text from an unsent message in iMessage. Is there anyway to access this information?

For example, when my extension is loaded is there a way to gain access to the "test" string in the below screenshot?

[image: 'Test' text inside text field]

I've tried poking around the `activeConversation` object but don't see anything related to the input field.